# Recovering lost information

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, storage

I installed a LVM storage on my computer and I had very important information inside `/HFT`.

Here is the way I installed that LVM storage:

1. `sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`
2. `sudo vgcreate VG /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`
3. `sudo lvcreate -n LV -L 3T VG`
4. `sudo mkfs .ext3 /dev/VG/LG` (could be `.ext4`)
5. `mkdir /HFT`
6. `sudo mount /dev/VG/LG /HFT`

Before restarting, I got a nice 3TB storage, I could see it clearly with `df -h`. Now, after restarting my computer, if I make `df -h`, I got

```
┌─╼ [~]
└╼ cd /dev
autofs           disk         fuse       i2c-11   input     loop-control        psaux   sdb   sg5       tty0   tty20  tty32  tty44  tty56      ttyS0   ttyS20  ttyS4      vboxdrvu    vcsa3
block            dm-0         fw0        i2c-12   kmsg      mapper              ptmx    sdb1  sg6       tty1   tty21  tty33  tty45  tty57      ttyS1   ttyS21  ttyS5      vboxnetctl  vcsa4
bsg              dm-1         hidraw0    i2c-13   kvm       mcelog              ptp0    sdc   sg7       tty10  tty22  tty34  tty46  tty58      ttyS10  ttyS22  ttyS6      vboxusb     vcsa5
btrfs-control    dm-2         hidraw1    i2c-14   lightnvm  mei0                ptp1    sdd   sg8       tty11  tty23  tty35  tty47  tty59      ttyS11  ttyS23  ttyS7      vcs         vcsa6
bus              dm-3         hidraw2    i2c-2    log       mem                 pts     sde   shm       tty12  tty24  tty36  tty48  tty6       ttyS12  ttyS24  ttyS8      vcs1        vfio
cdrom            dri          hidraw3    i2c-3    loop0     memory_bandwidth    random  sdf   snapshot  tty13  tty25  tty37  tty49  tty60      ttyS13  ttyS25  ttyS9      vcs2        vga_arbiter
cdrw             drm_dp_aux0  hidraw4    i2c-4    loop1     mqueue              rfkill  sdg   snd       tty14  tty26  tty38  tty5   tty61      ttyS14  ttyS26  ubuntu-vg  vcs3        vhci
char             dvd          hpet       i2c-5    loop2     net                 rtc     sdh   sr0       tty15  tty27  tty39  tty50  tty62      ttyS15  ttyS27  uhid       vcs4        vhost-net
console          dvdrw        hugepages  i2c-6    loop3     network_latency     rtc0    sg0   stderr    tty16  tty28  tty4   tty51  tty63      ttyS16  ttyS28  uinput     vcs5        vhost-vsock
core             ecryptfs     hwrng      i2c-7    loop4     network_throughput  sda     sg1   stdin     tty17  tty29  tty40  tty52  tty7       ttyS17  ttyS29  urandom    vcs6        zero
cpu              fb0          i2c-0      i2c-8    loop5     null                sda1    sg2   stdout    tty18  tty3   tty41  tty53  tty8       ttyS18  ttyS3   usb        vcsa
cpu_dma_latency  fd           i2c-1      i2c-9    loop6     port                sda2    sg3   tpm0      tty19  tty30  tty42  tty54  tty9       ttyS19  ttyS30  userio     vcsa1
cuse             full         i2c-10     initctl  loop7     ppp                 sda3    sg4   tty       tty2   tty31  tty43  tty55  ttyprintk  ttyS2   ttyS31  vboxdrv    vcsa2
┌─╼ [/dev]
└────╼ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        6.7G   11M  6.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  151G   61G   83G  43% /
tmpfs                         34G   29M   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    705M  401M  253M  62% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        6.7G   16K  6.7G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                        6.7G   20K  6.7G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/infinity/.Private      151G   61G   83G  43% /home/infinity
```

Now, `/HFT` still exists, but it is empty.

I don't know if I lost everything. Is there a way to restore information? Why is the whole procedure cleared up everything once I rebooted my computer? What is the proper way that such an error does not happen again in the future?

### UPDATE

```
sudo lvdisplay
  WARNING: Device for PV rat7TF-lEMd-U3Gi-29du-7Fn3-2bNC-9CVmqL not found or rejected by a filter.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VG/LV
  LV Name                LV
  VG Name                VG
  LV UUID                Bm0ThM-KWDU-oyjm-F8Zt-NXdF-yyFO-2rvM9d
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time infinity-ThinkStation-D30, 2018-04-16 15:00:57 -0400
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                3.00 TiB
  Current LE             786432
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                f1TYvS-XFq1-Z6Nu-iuXg-H95j-0XUN-8J4vi3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-11-14 13:28:06 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                154.38 GiB
  Current LE             39522
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                q2kHAa-Q3jc-8C1t-JQvi-PtTo-3KR4-zoNH2a
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-11-14 13:28:07 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                67.92 GiB
  Current LE             17387
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

### UPDATE 2

```
┌─╼ [/]
└────╼ fdisk -l /dev/sdc
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: Permission denied
┌─╼ [/]
└╼ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9619624a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I tried to run sudo mount `/dev/VG/LV /HFT`, but it seems not working fine. I've had the problem `mount: /HFT: special device /dev/VG/LV does not exist.`

### UPDATE 3

```
root@infinity-ThinkStation-D30:/HFT# lvchange -ay --activationmode partial /dev/VG/LV
  PARTIAL MODE. Incomplete logical volumes will be processed.
  WARNING: Device for PV rat7TF-lEMd-U3Gi-29du-7Fn3-2bNC-9CVmqL not found or rejected by a filter.

┌─╼ [/HFT]
└╼ sudo mount /dev/VG/LV /HFT
mount: /HFT: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/VG-LV.
```

Comment: 1.  You haven't mounted the filesystem yet

Comment: 2. If you have really important information on an LV, spreading it across two disks like you have is equivalent to halving the lifetime of a disk. If _either_ disk dies you will lose _all_ your data. I hope you have a backup somewhere else.

Comment: 3. Not entirely sure why you went to `/dev` to run `df -h`. They're not really connected like that.

Comment: 4. If in your step 4 you used ext3 instead of ext4 you're setting yourself up for pain later down the road. There is almost no reason to use ext3 nowadays.

Comment: `WARNING: Device for PV rat7TF-lEMd-U3Gi-29du-7Fn3-2bNC-9CVmqL not found or rejected by a filter.` is worrying; also I don't see `/dev/sdc1` in your listing (though I do see `/dev/sdc`)... Did something else happen to that disk?

Comment: What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` say?

Comment: I tried to run sudo mount `/dev/VG/LV /HFT`, but it seems not working fine. I've had the problem `mount: /HFT: special device /dev/VG/LV does not exist.`

Comment: @derobert missing `sdc1` is a good catch.

Comment: @roaima Anyhow that LVM storage exists. I am struggling to mount it.

Comment: Maybe a partial activation is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happened here is that you don't have `/dev/sdc1`, which contains half of the volume group `VG`. Without it you cannot activate `VG`, which in turn means you cannot access the logical volume `LV`.

Currently you no access to any of your data on `VG/LV`. It might be stored on the missing disk, or you might be lucky and enough of it might be on the disk that's present.

Non-invasive steps I would recommend you take:

1. Power off your system. Carefully check all the connectors for disk `/dev/sdc` to ensure it is fully connected. Restart.
2. Run `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` to see if the partition even exists.
3. Look in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` to see if there's a filter blocking access to your `/dev/sdc1`. Ignore all lines beginning with `#`. None of the rest should have a keyword that mentions `filter`.

Invasive steps I would not recommend you take unless everything else has failed:

1. Run `vgchange -ay /dev/VG --activationmode partial`

   THIS ↑ ↑ MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA. On the other hand it may let you recover it.
2. Run `mount -o ro,noload /dev/VG/LV /HFT` to mount what filesystem it can find and see if any of the data is present. If it is, copy it to a safe place and rebuild your LVM volume group. The mount is read-only so you won't be able to change anything in the LV.

---

As an aside, if you have important data there are two things you can do to mitigate its potential loss

1. Take regular automated backups. Preferably to a separate location. (I use a cloud storage provider.)
2. Use RAID 1 to mirror data across two same-sized disks. You'll need 2x 3TB disks to store 3TB data but it's worth it. Really it is. You can do this either using the `mdadm` RAID toolset or directly in LVM.

Comment: What cloud storage do you use? Like  `google drive`, and you pay $14 per month for that service?

Comment: What do you mean, "_it works fine_"? Your update 3 didn't use the solutions I suggested, and from what I can see you've got a broken filesystem.

Comment: I applied `vgchange -ay /dev/VG --activationmode partial` and `mount -o ro,noload /dev/VG/LV /HFT`, and I worked fine!